# Error using flot piechart

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot, pie-chart

I am trying to use flot pie chart API to generate pie charts on the data received from server.
I have looked at the examples given [here](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/pie.html) and other places.
I tried using the same code but for some reason it's not showing up properly.
This is the current output
[image]

And the code used for generating the chart:

```
$.plot($("#placeholder"), poll_data, {
series: {
    pie: {
    show: true
    }
},
legend: {
    show: false
}
});
<div id="placeholder" style="width: 250px; height: 250px;"></div>
```

Any idea why this is not working? Surprisingly, it works when I change legend show to true;

Comment: What version of Flot are you using?  This looks like a bug that we fixed recently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is fixed in the [master branch](https://github.com/flot/flot) ([zip](https://github.com/flot/flot/zipball/master)), which is currently at version 0.8-alpha; try using that.